# Is it possible to programatically use the new Chrome Edge engine in a third party application?

Tags: c#, .net, webview

The next version of Microsoft Edge will ditch its engine in favor of Chromium's. Is it possible to start using this new engine in a C# application? Will the current WebView just switch to it or is there a new control?

Comment: Have a look at [cefsharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) it's chromium embedded framework port for .NET

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski: I'm familiar with cefsharp, I used it before. I'm wondering about what the Microsoft native solution looks like. Is it out yet?

Comment: I don't think the WebView will change over to using Chromium.  I would bet that is still uses the IE engine (and probably not even IE11).

Comment: Modern WebView is using Edge under the hood https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2018/05/09/modern-webview-winforms-wpf-apps/